# javascript / jquery stacked horizontal sliding image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

So, I have this site I'm throwing together. My image gallery is pretty basic, but doesn't need to be dynamic anyway so I don't mind.

My question is this... I have the motion down, but I can't figure out how to collapse the image without it squashing the contents.

I either want them to slide nicely off the #container div, or have the vertical bars wipe between images... Not sure how to explain this in text.

Here's the site in question:

http://intwind.com/test/

Comment: please be more specific , didn't get the question

Comment: There are accordion plug-ins that already do this.

Comment: when I animate the width the browser naturally squashes the image. I'm trying to figure out a way to have it slide off the page, OR have the vertical navigation bars wipe between images. I'm not sure how else to describe it.

Comment: @Diodeus any suggestions for specific lightweight ones? or a way to do it with jquery?

Comment: There are lot of them for jQuery. #3 of this list looks like what you're trying to accomplish. http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-accordion-menus-tutorials/

Comment: I figured it out. overflow:hidden; on the containing div for the slider images, then leave them their normal width. Works perfectly!